# Visual Studio stucks at loading a project and solution needs to be reopened several times after a checkout from VCS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Here is the situation:

I checkout a new project  to directory. I open a solution and it stucks at loading project XYZ.
What I see is loading window and "Loading XYZ..." on the statusbar.

The solution we made up is the following:

1. Open the solution (let's say its name is Solution.sln) in a notepad
2. Remove the problematic XYZ project 
   for example:

   Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11A3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "HelloWorld.Tool.XYZ", "HelloWorld.Tool.XYZ\HelloWorld.Tool.XYZ.csproj", "{F614BEF7-B429-487D-9055-01BC9FD543EC}"
   EndProject
3. Reopen the solution

But when there are more such problematic projects in a solution
Visual Studio stucks at the other projects. Sometimes it happens that there are a few projects to remove at once then Visual Studio starts. Then I add projects via notepad one by one repeating the proccess of reopening solution.

As you see this proccess is often very tedious and time-consuming.

Why it happens? How to solve it in a simpler manner?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with Resharper

**EDIT:** Suspending Resharper didn't help